# VLC will not start DVD

Tags: vlc-media-player

I've set VLC as the default player on my Windows XP machine. If i have a DVD in the tray and dobbleclick on the H:\ (dvdrom) VLC starts but does not start playing like on a regular dvdplayer for TV. Its just black where I expected trailers and main menu to pop up.

Browsing the DVD and playing the vob files works :(

Does anybody have a good idea what it might be?

Comment: What version of VLC are you running?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could be a region problem - Check the back of the DVD case

A codec problem (although this is normally a probably with video files not DVDs)